# Python Matching License Plates

Tags: python, comparison

I am working on a traffic study and I have the following problem:

I have a CSV file that contains time-stamps and license plate numbers of cars for a location and another CSV file that contains the same thing. I am trying to find matching license plates between the two files and then find the time difference between the two. I know how to match strings but is there a way I can find matches that are close maybe to detect user input error of the license plate number?

Essentially the data looks like the following:

`A = [['09:02:56','ASD456'],...]
B = [...,['09:03:45','ASD456'],...]`

And I want to find the time difference between the two sightings but say if the data was entered slightly incorrect and the license plate for B says 'ASF456' that it will catch that

Comment: Can anyone help me subtract two timestamps that are strings? For example I want 09:42:00 - 09:41:00 to return 00:01:00

Comment: The datetime module is what you're looking for. datetime.datetime object support substraction and return a datetime.timedelta object which you can convert into seconds :
from datetime import datetime; tdelta = datetime.strptime(timestamp1, '%H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(timestamp2, '%H:%M:%S'); travel_time = tdelta.days*60*60*24 - tdelta.seconds
And then do whatever you need to with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).  You can perform matches like this:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a='ASD456'
>>> b='ASF456'
>>> seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a.lower(), b=b.lower())
>>> seq.ratio()
0.83333333333333337
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is about a fuzzy search, from what it sounds like.  Instead of checking string equality, you can check if the two string being compared have a levenshtein distance of 1 or less.  Levenshtein distance is basically a fancy way of saying how many insertions, deletions or changes will it take to get from word A to B.  This should account for small typos.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for the partial matching I would highly suggest using `nltk` it's a general purpose natural language toolkit that includes a number of useful algorithms for determining the difference between two strings. It includes edit distance (levenshtein distance) as well as many others and the ability to implement custom metrics.

```
http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.metrics.distance-module.html
```

However, depending on exactly what you're looking for it might make more sense to look for spell-checking instead. For that, depending on exactly what you'd like to do I would probably suggest `PyEnchant` assuming you have a number of license plates that you're trying to match with some other license plates you should make a dictionary that consists of "true" license plates and then call `enchant.suggest` on the one you're trying to match, which will return a number of plates in order of relevancy.

```
http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/
```

If you aren't a big fan of using external libraries (understandable) and would rather just write up some plain python, Peter Norvig wrote a great article on making a spell-checker in 20 lines that would work extremely well for this application. (basically it looks for 2-ply of insertions, deletions and translations)

```
http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use fuzzy matching in the [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) (soon to be in a [new](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0429/#features-for-3-4) Python distribution near you!)

```
>>> a='ASD456'
>>> b='ASF456'
>>> c='AXF456'
>>> regex.fullmatch('(?:{}){{s<=1}}'.format(a),b).group(0)
'ASF456'
>>> regex.fullmatch('(?:{}){{s<=2}}'.format(a),c).group(0)   # Note 2 substitutions allowed
'AXF456'
```